# AWS S3 EC2 Dilemma.

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

Recently my Web design firm got a big contract to build a website that will be media rich and **needs to run on wordpress**. The client wants it so because of the simplicity and familiarity with Wordpress they have.

The hosting will be undoubtedly with AWS EC2, and we are not torn into hosting the actual files on a separate instance or a S3 bucket. I have never worked with S3, but have some 2+ years experience with EC2. Users uploading images, videos, documents,...will be a big component of the website.

**ANTICIPATED:**   Based on the market stydy done by another firm for the client, we expect in the upwards of 1000 unique visitors daily, of whom 5-10% would be uploading on the server/bucket.

**AIM**: A fast website with that kind of media richess

Any advice as to the choice of the server / infrastructure settings/choices?

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress by default does however store all of its files in the local file system. You can get plugins to allow uploads to be stored in S3. Although with only 1000 uniques, it may not be necessary.

The biggest gain in speed is going to be with using caching systems (preferably caching to memory).

Comment: I forgot to mention for the sake of having control, we'll build every single plugin and the theme from the bottom up ourselves. I realized many themes nowadays carry a lot more junk than necessary.

Answer (score 2):

There are many options open to you, but with something like 1000 unique per day, you don't have much to worry about.  If you want to take advantage of the CDN part of S3 then:-

1. Create a bucket in S3, with public CDN options enabled
2. Mount this bucket using S3 FUSE in Linux -> Guide here
   http://juliensimon.blogspot.de/2013/08/howto-aws-mount-s3-buckets-from-linux.html
3. Ensure memory caching is enabled in Wordpress (W3 Cache)
4. Minify the CSS and JS files using W3 Cache (careful as this sometimes breaks the themes)
5. If site is not responsive enough consider using AWS CloudFront or CloudFlare
6. If the site much be online at all times then consider 2 instances with DNS roundrobin. Keep wordpress Sync'd using rsync.  Ensure they both mount the same S3 bucket.

This should be more than enough.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

1000 visitors a day is not really so large a strain on a server that I'd be too especially worried about it. If it were me, I'd make sure to use caching (like datasage recommended), and also looking into leveraging a CDN, especially since you're dealing with a lot of media. No matter what CDN you use, be it Cloudflare, MaxCDN, VideoPress, Amazon CloudFront, Akamai, or any one of many great content delivery network providers out there, I think you'll get a lot further with that than you will tweaking your server.  If you want to do that too, I'd suggest caching and NGINX. Obviously minify CSS and JS too, before you deploy, but that's kinda obvious

Comment: I am looking into CloudFront

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all the input as the concensus is that 1000 uniques / day is not much of a deal. Check

Need I to mention though that we'll build every single functionality ourselves as a main plugin to fully have control over the features. Many themes nowadays are stuffed with unnecessary junk which doesn't help the case we're trying to make. I will look at StuartB's solution more closely, but I certainly do appreciate all of your inputs.